# Error: package 'DBI' required by 'AnnotationDbi' could not be found in R(v 2.7.0)

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I install old version of R (windows version `2.7.0`).

For using bioconductor in R, use `source("http://bioconductor.org/getBioC.R")`

```
biocLite("GO.db")
library("GO.db")
```

When I load GO.db, it gives error:

> Loading required package: AnnotationDbi
>
> Error: package 'DBI' required by 'AnnotationDbi' could not be found

How can I solve this problem? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

R packages are often require or depend upon other packages. For example, `GO.db` requires `AnnotationDbi`. When a package in Bioconductor requires another Bioconductor package, it will usually just install both of them at the same time.

Unfortunately, there are times when a package from Bioconductor requires a package from CRAN, and you will need to install each package separately. In this case, `DBI` is required by `AnnotationDbi`, but it is on CRAN.

Try installing `DBI`:

```
install.packages("DBI")
```

Then try loading `GO.db`. You may have to re-install `AnnotationDbi` again to get it to work.